# mongodb setting up a database password

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I read through several docs on mongodb but I'm so confused that I'm posting this question.

Is there a way to set a password for a mongodb database? That ways when I try to open the database via console or connect using mongoose/node.js I will need a password.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the "auth" parameter to start mongod with required authentication.
Therefor you have to create an admin user (a user which has admin privilegs like - creating other users and so on) and then you can create a user for read, readwrite or write rights for specific databases.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/#create-administrative-user-with-roles
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/#create-user-with-roles

Important is, that you start your mongo db with the auth parameter after creating these users.

```
mongod --auth
```

Comment: What happens if someone just copies the database files and of they start the mongodb without the auth parameter.

Comment: If he could copy your database files, he has access to your system -> so he could copy your db config (with database credentials ;) ). If he only copies the database files, he has no access to the database without the credentials.

Comment: @bengtler: The database files are not encrypted at rest by default, so if you can copy the data files, it is possible to restart on a `mongod` without `--auth` to gain access to the data. There are a number of solutions for encryption at rest (eg. LUKS, Bitlocker, Vormetric, Guardium) if that level of security is required. For more details see the [MongoDB Security Guide](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/security/) and [MongoDB Security Architecture White Paper](http://info.mongodb.com/rs/mongodb/images/MongoDB_Security_Architecture_WP.pdf).